# How to safely delete old Besu data to free space?

Tags: besu

The ubutun server ran out of space and need to delete obsolete data under /database to free room. Here is a list of the output of ls command in /database subdirectory:

```
total 16965588
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    606128 May 29  2022 001481.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67542290 Jun  6  2022 001512.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67542536 Jun  6  2022 001517.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67542836 Jun  6  2022 001526.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67541937 Jun  6  2022 001527.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67541505 Jun  6  2022 001528.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67541270 Jun  6  2022 001529.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67541605 Jun  6  2022 001532.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67542809 Jun  6  2022 001533.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67541949 Jun  6  2022 001541.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67542130 Jun  6  2022 001558.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67541492 Jun  6  2022 001567.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67542870 Jun  6  2022 001572.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67541609 Jun  6  2022 001580.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67542427 Jun  6  2022 001585.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67416810 Jun  6  2022 001590.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67391820 Jun  6  2022 001591.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67390376 Jun  6  2022 001592.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67391136 Jun  6  2022 001593.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67389965 Jun  6  2022 001594.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67388378 Jun  6  2022 001595.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67380946 Jun  6  2022 001596.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67371484 Jun  6  2022 001603.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67360202 Jun  6  2022 001604.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67362962 Jun  6  2022 001605.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67363007 Jun  6  2022 001606.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67360486 Jun  6  2022 001607.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67360363 Jun  6  2022 001608.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67505687 Jun  6  2022 001614.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67507156 Jun  6  2022 001615.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    413664 Jun 25  2022 001658.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    195143 Aug 27 08:11 001944.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67361707 Oct  4 15:14 002197.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67363294 Oct  4 15:14 002198.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67359966 Oct  4 15:14 002199.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67511043 Oct 14 04:59 002252.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67386828 Oct 14 05:00 002262.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67387187 Oct 14 05:00 002263.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67544386 Oct 18 23:52 002286.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67543743 Oct 18 23:52 002287.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67543942 Oct 18 23:52 002288.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   1528634 Oct 18 23:52 002289.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67511313 Oct 23 18:45 002316.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67511796 Oct 23 18:45 002317.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  14053353 Oct 23 18:45 002318.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67545014 Oct 23 18:45 002319.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67545149 Oct 23 18:45 002320.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67545068 Oct 23 18:45 002321.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   1478462 Oct 23 18:45 002322.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67544484 Oct 28 13:38 002353.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67546157 Oct 28 13:38 002354.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67544880 Oct 28 13:38 002355.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    118717 Oct 28 13:38 002356.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67544401 Oct 28 13:38 002357.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67544374 Oct 28 13:38 002358.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67545488 Oct 28 13:38 002359.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   1497123 Oct 28 13:38 002360.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67543527 Nov  2 08:31 002389.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67545063 Nov  2 08:31 002390.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67545091 Nov  2 08:31 002391.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   1474562 Nov  2 08:31 002392.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67544376 Nov  2 08:31 002393.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67545682 Nov  2 08:31 002394.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67545623 Nov  2 08:31 002395.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   1471014 Nov  2 08:31 002396.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67545416 Nov  7 03:23 002428.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67545522 Nov  7 03:23 002429.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67546057 Nov  7 03:23 002430.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   1485261 Nov  7 03:23 002431.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67545847 Nov  7 03:23 002432.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67546282 Nov  7 03:23 002433.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67545265 Nov  7 03:23 002434.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   1486915 Nov  7 03:23 002435.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67543947 Nov 11 22:15 002454.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67544786 Nov 11 22:15 002455.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67543626 Nov 11 22:15 002456.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   1495673 Nov 11 22:15 002457.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67545118 Nov 11 22:16 002466.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67546950 Nov 11 22:16 002467.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67544729 Nov 11 22:16 002468.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   1461411 Nov 11 22:16 002469.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67544607 Nov 16 17:08 002491.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67545831 Nov 16 17:08 002492.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67544937 Nov 16 17:08 002493.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   1469060 Nov 16 17:08 002494.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67545285 Nov 21 12:01 002522.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67545251 Nov 21 12:01 002523.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67547220 Nov 21 12:01 002524.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   1437724 Nov 21 12:01 002525.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67545913 Nov 21 12:01 002526.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67547244 Nov 21 12:01 002527.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67545247 Nov 21 12:01 002528.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   1429041 Nov 21 12:01 002529.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67554356 Nov 26 06:54 002552.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67554203 Nov 26 06:54 002553.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67544936 Nov 26 06:54 002559.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67546905 Nov 26 06:54 002560.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67544386 Nov 26 06:54 002561.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   1463682 Nov 26 06:54 002562.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67545544 Nov 26 06:54 002563.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67545815 Nov 26 06:54 002564.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67544968 Nov 26 06:54 002565.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   1455807 Nov 26 06:54 002566.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  62500873 Dec  2 06:29 002573.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67546227 Dec  1 01:47 002588.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67547863 Dec  1 01:47 002589.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67544819 Dec  1 01:47 002590.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   1416458 Dec  1 01:47 002591.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67545463 Dec  1 01:47 002601.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67546554 Dec  1 01:47 002602.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67544374 Dec  1 01:47 002603.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   1423585 Dec  1 01:47 002604.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  62460536 Dec  3 11:12 002605.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  62464175 Dec  4 15:55 002607.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  62457158 Dec  5 20:38 002609.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  62464208 Dec  7 01:22 002611.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67545973 Dec  5 20:39 002627.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67547448 Dec  5 20:39 002628.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67545115 Dec  5 20:39 002629.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   1374141 Dec  5 20:39 002630.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  62463101 Dec  8 06:05 002631.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  62465539 Dec  9 10:48 002633.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  62455912 Dec 10 15:31 002635.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  62459459 Dec 11 20:14 002637.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67362342 Dec 10 15:32 002663.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  58391155 Dec 10 15:32 002664.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67545717 Dec 10 15:32 002665.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67546263 Dec 10 15:32 002666.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67544932 Dec 10 15:32 002667.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   1383568 Dec 10 15:32 002668.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  62466800 Dec 13 00:58 002669.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  62464385 Dec 14 05:41 002671.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  62459552 Dec 15 10:24 002673.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  62460716 Dec 16 15:07 002675.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67544710 Dec 15 10:25 002691.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67548377 Dec 15 10:25 002692.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67546081 Dec 15 10:25 002693.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   1298284 Dec 15 10:25 002694.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67544739 Dec 15 10:25 002699.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67546899 Dec 15 10:25 002700.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67544401 Dec 15 10:25 002701.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   1321814 Dec 15 10:25 002702.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  62463049 Dec 17 19:51 002703.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  62465518 Dec 19 00:34 002705.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  62457151 Dec 20 05:17 002707.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  62464349 Dec 21 10:00 002709.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67353068 Dec 20 05:17 002717.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67329046 Dec 20 05:17 002718.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67329437 Dec 20 05:17 002719.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67328874 Dec 20 05:17 002720.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67329096 Dec 20 05:17 002721.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67328386 Dec 20 05:17 002722.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67330597 Dec 20 05:17 002723.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  29872086 Dec 20 05:17 002724.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  14456202 Dec 20 05:18 002733.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67545604 Dec 20 05:18 002734.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67546314 Dec 20 05:18 002735.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67544160 Dec 20 05:18 002736.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   1285619 Dec 20 05:18 002737.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67544840 Dec 20 05:18 002738.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67546470 Dec 20 05:18 002739.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67547585 Dec 20 05:18 002740.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   8075991 Dec 20 05:18 002741.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  62459619 Dec 22 14:43 002742.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  62463176 Dec 23 19:27 002744.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  62454726 Dec 25 00:10 002746.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  62457013 Dec 26 04:53 002748.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67549097 Dec 25 00:10 002764.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67550873 Dec 25 00:10 002765.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67549088 Dec 25 00:10 002766.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  59818318 Dec 25 00:10 002767.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67546108 Dec 25 00:10 002768.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67546276 Dec 25 00:10 002769.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67544142 Dec 25 00:10 002770.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   1307223 Dec 25 00:10 002771.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  62459476 Dec 27 09:36 002772.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  62465567 Dec 28 14:19 002774.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  62459574 Dec 29 19:02 002776.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  62464407 Dec 30 23:45 002778.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  22862390 Dec 29 19:03 002792.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67548432 Dec 29 19:03 002793.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67549637 Dec 29 19:03 002794.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67551342 Dec 29 19:03 002795.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67549715 Dec 29 19:03 002796.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67551722 Dec 29 19:03 002797.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67552566 Dec 29 19:03 002798.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67552982 Dec 29 19:03 002799.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   9410117 Dec 29 19:03 002800.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67513588 Dec 29 19:03 002801.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67514873 Dec 29 19:03 002802.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67514162 Dec 29 19:03 002804.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67513450 Dec 29 19:03 002805.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  18871849 Dec 29 19:03 002806.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67546497 Dec 29 19:03 002808.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67546224 Dec 29 19:03 002809.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   1281589 Dec 29 19:03 002810.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  62464417 Jan  1 04:29 002811.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  62457156 Jan  2 09:12 002813.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  62455912 Jan  3 13:55 002815.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  62459545 Jan  4 18:38 002817.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67550216 Jan  3 13:55 002825.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67549233 Jan  3 13:55 002827.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67551807 Jan  3 13:55 002828.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67551701 Jan  3 13:55 002829.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67546913 Jan  3 13:55 002830.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  56329713 Jan  3 13:55 002831.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   3057679 Jan  3 13:55 002832.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67547393 Jan  3 13:55 002833.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67546965 Jan  3 13:55 002834.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67545790 Jan  3 13:55 002835.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   1225334 Jan  3 13:55 002836.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  62461943 Jan  5 23:21 002837.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  62463175 Jan  7 04:04 002839.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  62465625 Jan  8 08:48 002841.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  62464397 Jan  9 13:31 002843.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67555501 Jan  8 08:48 002845.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67556520 Jan  8 08:48 002846.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  38407284 Jan  8 08:48 002848.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67336975 Jan  8 08:48 002849.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   5316355 Jan  8 08:48 002851.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67550113 Jan  8 08:48 002852.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67549661 Jan  8 08:48 002853.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67549143 Jan  8 08:48 002854.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67549973 Jan  8 08:48 002855.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67550296 Jan  8 08:48 002856.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67548981 Jan  8 08:48 002857.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67549788 Jan  8 08:48 002858.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   2636035 Jan  8 08:48 002859.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67324533 Jan  8 08:48 002862.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67316255 Jan  8 08:48 002863.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67390746 Jan  8 08:48 002864.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67467920 Jan  8 08:48 002865.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67452120 Jan  8 08:48 002866.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67383231 Jan  8 08:48 002867.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67385412 Jan  8 08:49 002868.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67384735 Jan  8 08:49 002870.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67385852 Jan  8 08:49 002871.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  33754085 Jan  8 08:49 002872.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  47436120 Jan 10 11:21 002873.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  29484824 Jan  9 13:31 002874.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  22303310 Jan 10 11:21 002878.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     14222 Jan 10 11:21 002879.sst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  38042085 Jan 11 04:51 002881.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root        16 Jan 10 11:21 CURRENT
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root        37 Sep 24  2021 IDENTITY
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root         0 Sep 24  2021 LOCK
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   5184741 Jan 11 04:42 LOG
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 340388297 Nov  8  2021 LOG.old.1636344024943029
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    877271 Nov  8  2021 LOG.old.1636353201418395
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  39103231 Nov 13  2021 LOG.old.1636758543409135
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    152935 Nov 13  2021 LOG.old.1636759068885762
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    134243 Nov 13  2021 LOG.old.1636759797021765
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    292673 Nov 13  2021 LOG.old.1636763085456381
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    350120 Nov 13  2021 LOG.old.1636766983704473
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    145109 Nov 13  2021 LOG.old.1636767869867262
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    668238 Nov 13  2021 LOG.old.1636774957987563
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    341473 Nov 13  2021 LOG.old.1636779639198366
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 289835058 Dec 18  2021 LOG.old.1639808388261666
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  20616107 Dec 21  2021 LOG.old.1640027098163385
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   1813041 Dec 21  2021 LOG.old.1640046298835492
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    234945 Dec 21  2021 LOG.old.1640047892885068
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    187014 Dec 21  2021 LOG.old.1640050440431197
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    735374 Dec 21  2021 LOG.old.1640057814868181
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    556071 Dec 21  2021 LOG.old.1640063741049991
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    134130 Dec 21  2021 LOG.old.1640064541180568
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    676502 Dec 21  2021 LOG.old.1640070702318998
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    196757 Dec 21  2021 LOG.old.1640072524995227
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    134350 Dec 21  2021 LOG.old.1640072986909852
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    134277 Dec 21  2021 LOG.old.1640073945549892
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   3458487 Dec 22  2021 LOG.old.1640114679390661
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 425686161 Feb 11  2022 LOG.old.1644533005867804
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 971914569 May 29  2022 LOG.old.1653785514499880
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 247283409 Jun 25  2022 LOG.old.1656102974623058
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 453965848 Aug 27 08:06 LOG.old.1661558951993290
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 979272770 Jan 10 11:20 LOG.old.1673320846662223
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     26224 Jan 10 11:21 MANIFEST-002880
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     44287 Jan 10 11:21 OPTIONS-002903
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     44288 Jan 10 11:21 OPTIONS-002905
```

There is crypto coin smart contract deployed very early on besu network and it shall be un-touched and kept. Which files can be safely deleted without breaking the normal operation of the besu network?

Answer (score 1):

You can safely do `rm LOG.o*` to remove all the old log files but that is it